# How do I check if express server is running from python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, express

So I call my `backend.js` from my python code like this

```py
# server is requested to start
startServer = subprocess.Popen(['node', 'backend.js'])
# startServer.wait()
if startServer.poll:
    print('Server could not be started')
    sys.exit()
```

And my `backend.js` contains

```js
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

How can the backend tell python that server for some reason failed to start and exit the program or server has started and now you can go ahead? I have tried waiting for the startServer to end but that just stops the python code until server is stopped. So is there a way by which the callback function in `app.listen` can send information to the python code?

Comment: I'm no expert in Python, but you can always implement a `health` endpoint in your JS backend and, once you ran your subprocess, query the `health` endpoint via Python. `health` endpoints usually just return a HTTP 200 response, to indicate the system is healthy, so if you do not have a HTTP 200 from this endpoint, you know there's something going on. There probably is a more classy and efficient way to do this though.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals Thanks will look into that. Yes there might be a better way I think popen can communicate with the subprocess and check what they are logging/printing I will look into it later today and update here.